# Issues with changing cursor image on change of cursor - Canvas Drawing App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating a canvas drawing app and I want to be able to load my cursor images for each tool while clicking on the tool. I had this working until I did a little redecorating and changed the layout. I put the tools inside a table with the redesign, but I don't think this should be the problem. Thank you for all your help.

```
      ****************HTML**********************                 


 <div class="tools2">



  <table>                             
     <tr>
     <th>
     <div id="brush">
    <input type="image" class="line" src="./assets/imgs/tools/brush.png" />
     </div>
     </th>
     <th>  
     <div id="bucket">
   <input type="image" class="line" src="./assets/imgs/tools/bucket.png" onclick="setFill()" />
      </div>
      </th>
      <th> 
      <div id="eraser">
      <input type="image" class="line" src="./assets/imgs/tools/eraser.png" onclick="setEraser()" />
      </div>
       </th>
       <th>
       <div>
       <form onsubmit='return false;'>
       <input type='image' src="./assets/imgs/tools/clear_brush.png"  class="line" id="clear" onclick='clear_canvas_rectangle ()'>                          
       </form> 
       </div>      
        </th> 
        </tr>
       </table>
```

```
   ****************JQUERY********************** 

<script> 


   $('.tools2 a div').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function () {
            setCursor($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });






function setCursor(id) {
    console.log("init.js: setCursor(): id: " + id);

    switch (id) {
        case 'brush':
            shape = SHAPE_TYPE.LINE;
        break;
        case 'circle':
            shape = SHAPE_TYPE.CIRCLE;
        break;
        case 'rectangle':
            shape = SHAPE_TYPE.RECTANGLE;
        break;
        case 'eraser':
            shape = SHAPE_TYPE.ERASER;
        break;
        case 'fill':
            shape = SHAPE_TYPE.FILL;
        break;


    }

    console.log("image path: " + 'cursor_' + id + '.png');

$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_' + id + '.png)0 130, auto');





$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/brush.png) 0 0, auto');
}

function setLine(){
    console.log('init.js: setLine(): brush');
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.LINE;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_brush.png)0 130, auto');
}

function setEraser(){

    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.ERASER;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_eraser.png) 0 130, auto');
}
function setFill(){
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.FILL;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/bucket.png) 0 130, auto');
}

function setCircle(){
    console.log('init.js: setCircle(): circle');
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.CIRCLE;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_circle.png)0 130, auto');
}
function setRectangle(){
    console.log('init.js: setRectangle(): rect');
    shape = SHAPE_TYPE.RECTANGLE;
    $('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/imgs/tools/cursor_rectangle.png)0 130, auto');



}
```

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to define all the different cursors in CSS, then change the class name on the canvas based on the user selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the number "2" in the class `<div class="tools">`

second the path is wrong, corretion:

```
 $('.tools table tr th div').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            setCursor($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nr6yn2yz/

Comment: I made the corrections and this did work as far as changing the cursor back to the brush when clicked on, and everything is working and calling properly in the console. I can't seem to get the cursor off the brush image to change to another image of a tool though. I'm baffled by this because it is working and there are no errors. I have all the cursors set to 128px x 128px so I don't think it is a sizing problem??

Comment: Can you open a new question? and give a little more details maybe some screenshot... maybe this question can help other person

Comment: you're right, I opened a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800914/standard-sizing-for-cross-browser-cursor-images-jquery-change-of-cursor-images?noredirect=1#comment63070634_37800914