# standard sizing for cross browser cursor images?? jquery change of cursor images

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, png, image-size

My cursor images were working as saved 128px x 128px pngs but now they are not in any browser :( did something change?? I have posted a problem a few days ago regarding my cursor images not changing with a onclick for my drawing application. I had help with my initial problem and you can see it is being called properly in the console and everything is great, but the image won't change from the brush image. I think it might be something to do with the sizing but I am not 100% sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

***************HTML*************************

```
<div class="tools">
<table>
<tr>
<th>
<div id="brush">
<input type="image" class="line" src="./assets/tools/brush.png" />
</div>
</th>
<th> 
<div id="bucket">
<input type="image" class="line" src="./assets/tools/bucket.png" onclick="setFill()" />
</div>
</th>
<th> 
<div id="eraser">
<input type="image" class="line" src="./assets/tools/eraser.png" onclick="setEraser()" />
</div>
</th>
<th>
<div>
<form onsubmit='return false;'>
<input type='image' src="./assets/tools/clear_brush.png" class="line" id="clear" onclick='clear_canvas_rectangle ()'> 
</form> 
</div> 

</th> 

</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**************************JS*******************************

```
$('.tools table tr th div').each(function() {
$(this).click(function () {
console.log($(this).attr('id
setCursor($(this).attr('id'));
});
});



function setCursor(id) {
console.log("init.jsCursor(): id: " + id);

switch (id) {
case 'brush':
shape = SHAPE_TYPE.LINE;
break;
case 'eraser':
shape = SHAPE_TYPE.ERASER;
break;
case 'fill':
shape = SHAPE_TYPE.FILL;
break;


}



console.log("image: " + 'cursor_' + id + '.png');

$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/tools/cursor_' + id + '.png)0 130, auto');


$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/tools/cursor_brush.png) 0 130, auto');
}

function setLine(){
console.log('init.jstLine(): brush');
shape = SHAPE_TYPE.LINE;
$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/tools/cursor_brush.png)0 130, auto');
}

function setEraser(){
console.log('init.jstEraser(): eraser');
shape = SHAPE_TYPE.ERASER;
$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/tools/cursor_eraser.png)0 130, auto');
}


function setFill(){
shape = SHAPE_TYPE.FILL;
$('.canvas-boards').css('cursor', 'url(../assets/tools/cursor_bucket.png)30 120, auto');
}
```

Comment: The general recommended size limit for cursors is 32 by 32 and this is due to OS considerations rather than browser limitations. More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property As for why your cursors have stopped working, you do not supply enough details to determin. Check that the relative path is correct and that the resources are available by testing if you can load the cursor as an image.

Comment: Send me the console error

Comment: there isnt a console error it is going through correctly with the console an even stating the correct image path that it is supposed to go (showing below) but it is still not switching from the brush.                                      init.js: setLine(): brush
init.js:1 brush
init.js:1 init.js: setCursor(): id: brush
init.js:1 image path: cursor_brush.png                                                      init.js: setEraser(): eraser
init.js:1 eraser
init.js:1 init.js: setCursor(): id: eraser
init.js:1 image path: cursor_eraser.png